# Select in a reactive form doesn´t show anything

Tags: angular, forms, select, angular-reactive-forms

For Angular I found an example of a working select, I´m trying to use it now on a reactive form to show some areas, but I had to make changes and the select shows nothing. The example is a bit different, I tried some examples I´ve seen on the web, but I cant make it work.

```
export class RegistrarColaboradorComponent implements OnInit {
  hoy: Date = new Date();

  colaborador: Colaborador = {
    numeroDeIndentificacion: null,
    nombres: null,
    apellidos: null,
    direccion: null,
    email: null,
    telefono: null,
    salario: null,
    fk_Area: null,    
    fechaDeIngreso: null,
    sexo: null,
    codigoInterno: null
  };

   
  areas: Area[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      nombre: "Contabilidad"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      nombre: "Sistemas"
    }
  ];

  myForm: FormGroup;    
  submitted = false;    
  elCodigoInterno: string;  

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private dataService: DataService) { }
    
  iniciarFormulario(){
      this.myForm = new FormGroup({        
        numeroDeIndentificacion: new FormControl(this.colaborador.numeroDeIndentificacion, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(30)]),
        nombres: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(30)]),
        apellidos: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(30)]),
        direccion: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(30)]),
        email: new FormControl('', [Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(30)]),
        telefono: new FormControl('', [Validators.minLength(7), Validators.maxLength(15)]),        
        salario: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(5)]),            
        area: new FormControl(''),                   
        fechaDeIngreso: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        sexo: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        codigoInterno: new FormControl(this.colaborador.codigoInterno)
      });
  }

  

  ngOnInit() {    
    this.dataService.getCodigoInterno().subscribe(
      //result => console.log('success ', result),
      result => this.elCodigoInterno = result,
      error => console.log('error ', error)
    );

    this.dataService.obtenerAreas().subscribe(
      //result => console.log('success ', result),
      result => this.areas = result,
      error => console.log('error ', error)
    );

    this.iniciarFormulario();   
  }
```

This is the form

```
<form class="theForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="myForm">
...

  <div class="container">
        <select formControlName="area">
           <option>Seleccione el area</option>
           <option *ngFor="let area of areas" value="area.id">{{area.nombre}}</option>
        </select>
     </div>
```

Is there something missing? How can I make it work?

Comment: create a stackblitz sample

Comment: have you try read this -> https://www.positronx.io/angular-7-select-dropdown-examples-with-reactive-forms/

Comment: or try this one => `<option *ngFor="let area of areas" [ngValue]="area.id">{{area.nombre}}</option>`

Comment: Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'option'

Answer (score 0):

If I change your `ngOnInit()` to

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.iniciarFormulario();
    timer(50).subscribe(() => {
      this.areas = [
        {
          id: 1,
          nombre: 'Berge',
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          nombre: 'Seen',
        },
      ];
    });
  }
```

it works (cmp. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-cc15ha?file=app/app.component.ts)

So the root cause resides around getting the data in the right format from the service. In case you get the data from the backend, you can check the data received in the `DevTools` of Chrome in the `Network` tab.

[image]

Otherwise the `console.log('success ', result)` you already have (commented out) should be sufficient to see the data.